# How to find the limit of an algebraic sigmoid function

Tags: limits

$f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

How to find upper and lower limits of the above algebraic sigmoid function, respectively when $x >>0$ and $x << 0$?
I know these are $+1$ and $-1$ but unable to find it mathematically by limit finding methods. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Because for large $|x|$ we have$$\sqrt{x^2+1}\approx\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$$

Comment: You want limit of $f(x)$ when $x$ goes to infinity ?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to \pm \infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\lim_{x\to \pm\infty} \frac{x}{|x|\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+1}}$$ Divide top and bottom by $x$: $$= \lim_{x\to\pm\infty} \frac{ 1}{\pm 1\cdot \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+1}} =  \pm 1$$

Comment: Thank you Tavish. Your answer is useful. Just a slight modification to make it look cleaner. I would rather write $f(x)$ as $\frac{x}{|x|\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2} + 1}}$ by taking out $\sqrt{x^2}$, i.e. $|x|$ in the denominator. Now taking the limits $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$ would yield limiting values to be $\pm 1$.

Comment: @deepesh I agree. Edited.